# Core Image Filter iOS UISlider

Tags: ios, filter, uiimageview, uislider, core-image

I'm trying to implement a sepia filter on an image loaded into the UI View from the photo library.

I have a UI Slider...range -1 to 1. And applying the effect Sepia.

The problem I'm having is, the over all effect is getting summed up. Like...if I put slider to 1, then move it back to 0. It doesn't bring the image back to the original form. And I move it back to 1..total sepia is applied 2 times.

```
- (IBAction)slidermove:(id)sender {

    currentValue=_sliderValue.value;

    if (currentButton==1)
    {
        //1
        CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)];

        //2
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

        //3
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                      keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,
                            @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentValue], nil];

        //4
        CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

        CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

        //5
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

        //6
        CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    }


}



- (IBAction)applyeffect:(id)sender
{
    currentButton=1;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you don't save the original image. You change the image each time the slider changes, so the effect compounds. Here is what you should do instead:

In your `@interface`:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)UIImage *originalImage;
```

In your `@implementation`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = self.originalImage;
}
```

Then when you do the effect, apply it to the `originalImage` property and show the result in self.imageView.

Comment: Even better, I'd recommend not recreating the filter, context, and initial CIImage every time you move the slider. That's going to be horribly expensive. Instead, create the context, initial CIImage, and filter once and simply adjust values with the slider. Even better, don't render to a UIImage and UIImageView, but instead render your result to an OpenGL ES context for your live update and only pull down a full UIImage at the point that you need it.

Comment: 68cherries, when I'm using the original image in beginImage, as soon as I move the slider, the image disappears.

        CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.originalImage)];

Comment: You should verify that `self.originalImage` is set at that point in your code.